# Why isn't the host auto pulling the changes?

Tags: automation, puppet, puppet-enterprise

My host isn't pulling the changes automatically(at-least once in 30 minutes). I have to manually force it every time to see the changes. Am I missing any parameter/resource description in init.pp? My init.pp looks like below:

```
class checkout {
file { '/example/test12/test.sh':
ensure  => directory,
 mode    => '0755',
 recurse => true,
source  => 'puppet:///extra/'
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifests (`init.pp`, for instance) specify *what* to apply, not when to apply it.  It is the configuration of each agent that determines how often it performs a catalog run.  If you can trigger a catalog run manually, but runs do not happen automatically, then the most likely conclusion is that the puppet agent service is not running.  Alternatively, it may be that the agent in question is configured with a longer run interval than you thought -- the 30 minutes is just a default.

Comment: I can see the puppet agent service was stopped in both master and host. I never stopped it but have restarted it few times. Is there a way it would stop by itself? Having said that, puppet was still doing it's job(my different manifest and init.pp) even the service shows as stopped. And for that interval, it's still 30 minutes as default.

Comment: Btw, it solved the issue. The host was stopped, but I don't know how. It's so strange.

Comment: It is possible to make puppet ensure that the agent service is stopped.  Also, it is possible to run the agent via an external scheduler, such as `cron`, instead of running it as a service in its own right.  If the master appeared to be stopped but you were still able to obtain fresh catalogs, then you were looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: Master and almost all the hosts were stopped. But as you said, I was using a cron which does something once every week, and it was doing its job well. Recently I created a new init.pp for different purpose and had few resources were defined there, including "recurse => true". I am assuming that or something might have stopped it. Plus is there a way to start host at once or I have to do it manually? I have around 50 hosts.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that you can put in a manifest that would cause the agent or master to stop is a `Service` resource that explicitly ensures the service stopped.  If you have such a thing then it would stop the service every time you run the agent, but I think you would know about that.  More likely you have some external factor contributing.  It might be as simple as having rebooted the machines, but not having the agent (or master) configured to start automatically at boot.

Comment: As for starting the agent services on your hosts, I assure you that any appearance of magic that Puppet exhibits is actually a product of engineering.  You cannot do anything to any host without that host's cooperation.  PuppetLabs does offer a remote control system called MCollective -- I'm uncertain whether it's integrated into Puppet Enterprise -- but that has its own per-host service that must be running for the host to be remotely controllable by that means.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for all the answers and suggestions.